# How to create and use a Sitemap index in Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, sitemap

I am using the following npm package [sitemap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sitemap). It works as expected with the basic sitemap.xml. However, the documentation for Sitemap Index seems incomplete. I have used the following code snippet...

```
var sm = require('sitemap')
  , smi = sm.createSitemapIndex({
      cacheTime: 600000,
      hostname: 'http://localhost:2000',
      sitemapName: 'sm-test',
      sitemapSize: 1,
      targetFolder: require('os').tmpdir(),
      urls: ['http://ya.ru', 'http://ya2.ru']
      // optional: 
      // callback: function(err, result) {} 
    });
```

I am not sure how to test the sitemap Index. Please advice.

Answer (score 4):

If you've list of sitemap urls and you want them to add to a sitemap index, use **buildSitemapIndex**

```
    var sitemap = sm.buildSitemapIndex({
       urls: ['http://example.com/sitemap1.xml','http://example.com/sitemap.xml']
    });
```

and write it to sitemap index file.

```
fs.writeFileSync("./sitemapindex.xml", sitemap.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

With [sitemap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sitemap) index, you see some config:

> targetFolder: >> it will save file .xml into here

So when you run code

```
var sm = require('sitemap')
  , smi = sm.createSitemapIndex({
      cacheTime: 600000,
      hostname: 'http://localhost:2000',
      sitemapName: 'sm-test',
      sitemapSize: 1,
      targetFolder: require('os').tmpdir(),
      urls: ['http://ya.ru', 'http://ya2.ru']
      // optional: 
      // callback: function(err, result) {} 
    });
```

> file sm-test-index.xml will be create in targetFolder (Ex Window:
>   User/AppData/Local/Temp)

Hope it will help you.

Thanks.

> See more: sitemap/lib/sitemap.js in package